# Could not export whole database using MongoDB in Ubuntu

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

I need one help. I need to export and import the total database/all collection for MongoDB using Ubuntu. I am explaining my command below.

```
 sudo mongoexport --db FGDP --out  /home/subrajyoti/Downloads/newdbexport.json;
```

Here i am getting the following error message.

```
2016-12-22T10:28:46.290+0530    error validating settings: must specify a collection
2016-12-22T10:28:46.290+0530    try 'mongoexport --help' for more information
```

Here i need to export all collection rather than one single one. Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

Exporting all collections of all database using mongodump use the following command:

```
mongodump -o <directory_backup>
```

Comment: @ Mital Gajjar : Can you please say how can I transfer mongodb database from one host to another. suppose my db `FHDP` is present in this `10.25.*.*` ip and i want to move directly to 54.25.*.*. HOw can I do this.